# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'lookup_type'

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

Please help me why this error coming on remote server but it was work fine on local machine, please find below error sample.

```
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    https:***********.***?job_function=dir&job_type=parttime&max_experience=100&min_experience=3&name=test&owner_id=571&page_size=10
Django Version:     1.8.14
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'lookup_type'

Exception Location:     env/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/forms/fields.py in __init__, line 245
Python Executable:  env/bin/python3.4
Python Version:     3.4.3
Python Path:    

 '/home/deployment/backend',
 '/home/deployment/backend/env/bin',
 '/home/deployment/backend',
 '',
 '/home/deployment/backend/env/local/lib64/python3.4/site-packages',
 '/home/deployment/backend/env/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages',
 '/home/deployment/backend/env/lib64/python3.4',
 '/home/deployment/backend/env/lib/python3.4',
 '/home/deployment/backend/env/lib64/python3.4/site-packages',
 '/home/deployment/backend/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages',
 '/home/deployment/backend/env/lib64/python3.4/plat-linux',
 '/home/deployment/backend/env/lib64/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/home/deployment/backend/env/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib64/python3.4',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4'
```

> Code:

Please find the given code here, it's work on local machine fine but remote server through error, here two function defined in Jobviewsets class

def get_annotate_queryset(self, queryset):

```
#queryset = queryset.filter(Q(job_for='all') | Q(job_for=''))
queryset = queryset.annotate(
    all_applicant_count=Count('applicants', distinct=True),
    job_view_count=Count('job_views', distinct=True),
).extra(select={
    'voteup_count': get_voteup_count_query(queryset.model),
    'has_applied':
        """
        SELECT Sum(CASE WHEN {job_applicant}.user_id = {user_id} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        FROM {job_applicant}
        WHERE job_id={job}.id
        """.format(user_id=self.request.user.id,
            job=Job._meta.db_table,
            job_applicant=Applicant._meta.db_table),
    'is_favourite':
        """
        SELECT Sum(CASE WHEN {favourite_job}.user_id = {user_id} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        FROM {favourite_job}
        WHERE job_id={job}.id
        """.format(user_id=self.request.user.id,
            job=Job._meta.db_table,
            favourite_job=FavouriteJob._meta.db_table)
})
return queryset
```

def get_queryset(self):

```
queryset = super().get_queryset()
queryset = self.get_annotate_queryset(queryset)
if self.action == 'discover':

    searchtype=self.request.GET.get('search_type')
    searchKeyword=self.request.GET.get('name')
    searchLocation=self.request.GET.get('location')

    job_status=self.request.GET.get('job_status')
    if(job_status =='' or job_status== None):
        job_status = 'active'

    job_type=self.request.GET.get('job_type')
    if (job_type =='' or job_type == None):
        job_type = 'fulltime'

    min_experience=self.request.GET.get('min_experience')
    if (min_experience =='' or min_experience == None):
        min_experience = 0

    max_experience=self.request.GET.get('max_experience')
    if (max_experience =='' or max_experience == None):
        max_experience = 100

    min_salary_compensation=self.request.GET.get('min_salary_compensation')
    if (min_salary_compensation == None):
        min_salary_compensation = 0

    max_salary_compensation=self.request.GET.get('max_salary_compensation')
    if (max_salary_compensation =='' or max_salary_compensation == None):
        max_salary_compensation = 500000

    salary_reccurence=self.request.GET.get('salary_reccurence')
    if (salary_reccurence =='' or salary_reccurence == None):
        salary_reccurence = 'hourly'

    if (searchtype == 'refine_search'):

        if (searchKeyword == '' or searchKeyword == None):
            searchKeyword = ''

        if (searchLocation == '' or searchLocation == None):
            searchLocation = ''

        min_experience = int(min_experience)
        max_experience = int(max_experience)
        min_salary_compensation = int(min_salary_compensation)
        max_salary_compensation = int(max_salary_compensation)

        queryset = queryset.filter(Q(job_title__icontains=searchKeyword) |
                                   Q(company_name__icontains=searchKeyword) |
                                   Q(location_id=searchLocation) |
                                   Q(status=job_status) |
                                   Q(employment_type__icontains=job_type) |
                                   Q(min_experience__gte=min_experience) &
                                   Q(max_experience__lte=max_experience) |

                                   Q(compensation__gte=min_salary_compensation) &
                                   Q(compensation__lte=max_salary_compensation) |
                                   Q(salary_reccurence__icontains=salary_reccurence)

                                   ).exclude(owner=self.request.user)

    if (searchtype != 'refine_search'):

        if (searchKeyword != None and searchLocation != None):

            queryset = queryset.filter(Q(job_title__icontains=searchKeyword) |
                                       Q(company_name__icontains=searchKeyword) |
                                       Q(location_id=searchLocation)).exclude(owner=self.request.user)

        elif (searchKeyword != None and searchLocation == None):
            queryset = queryset.filter(Q(job_title__icontains=searchKeyword) |
                                       Q(company_name__icontains=searchKeyword)).exclude(
                owner=self.request.user)

        elif (searchKeyword == None and searchLocation != None):
            queryset = queryset.filter(Q(location_id=searchLocation)).exclude(owner=self.request.user)

        else:
            queryset = queryset.exclude(owner=self.request.user)

return queryset
```

Comment: There isn't enough information to find what's going on.

Comment: updated the code plz look it once from your side,
issue coming in if (searchtype == 'refine_search'):  condition and on local machine it work fine but not on remote server

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I have the same error on django 1.11 and python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

We will need to see the constructor method of the class that is being instantiated to figure out exactly what is going wrong.

However just from the error message it seems that there is an additional argument being passed to the constructor that is not recognized. Have a look at the formal parameters defined in the classes' constructor and compare that to the arguments being passed in.

Comment: I have updated code please review it once, error coming in if (searchtype == 'refine_search'): block and only on remote server on local same code works fine